# ios - How to invoke ScriptNotify in NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm getting an error in the following code like 'ScriptNotify' undeclared

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if(_data)
    {
        [_data release];
        _data = nil;
    }
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    if(!_data)

    {
        _data = [data mutableCopy];
    }
    else
    {
        [_data appendData:data];
    }
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if(_data)
    {
        NSString* content = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_data
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [_data release];
        _data = nil;

        // prepend the HTML with our custom JavaScript
        content = [ScriptNotify stringByAppendingString:content];

        [_webView loadHTMLString:content baseURL:_url];
    }
}
```

How to solve this?Any ideas?

Comment: what is ScriptNotify?

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific. What is "ScriptNotify"? It's not in the code you've provided. What have you tried? What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Please go through this link http://www.stevesaxon.me/posts/2011/window-external-notify-in-ios-uiwebview/

Comment: you need to set delegate of NSURLConnection object to invoke this delegate method `NSURLConnection *cn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];`

Comment: To save everyone else the hassle, by looking at stevesaxon's site, it looks like ScriptNotify is something like :-
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        window.external =
        {
             'Notify': function(s) { document.location = 'acs://settoken?token=' + s; },
             'notify': function(s) { document.location = 'acs://settoken?token=' + s; }
        };
    </script>
@Udhaya, you should amend your question if this is correct.

Secondly, this is really an HTML problem.  I recommend you retag with UIWebView and post the complete contents of 'content'.

Comment: Basically it all revolves around the problem that people DONT CARE ABOUT CODING STANDARDS! If author would not use ScriptNotify I woudlnt spent time looking around for a class ScriptNotify, gosh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, a light has gone on.

This answer will only make sense after reading the article Udhaya refers to.

In the article, Steve Saxon defines ScriptNotify as some like "the piece of javascript I described earlier", Objective C isn't that smart, so you'll have to tell it what this is.  Something like :-

```
NSString* ScriptNotify = @"
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
    window.external =
    {
        'Notify': function(s) { document.location = 'acs://settoken?token=' + s; },
        'notify': function(s) { document.location = 'acs://settoken?token=' + s; }
    };
    </script>
";
```

Things to do next time :-
Tell us that it is a compiler error.
Learn the language a bit better, this is really incredibly basic.
Post a comment on the Steve Saxon's page instead, this is his error.